# install extension civibooking

Tags: extension, installation, civibooking

As the installer gave us a warning that we maybe will have issues with http Redirect, so we did a Manual Installation of civibooking.

Now we cannot find any indicator that the process really was successfull and we cannot use it. What went wrong?

If we do it a 2nd time we get the DB-Information "already exists".

Please help!

running plesk 12.5 
php 5.5.9
MySQL 5.5.53
and ignoring SSL for the Moment.

BR
Jochen

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  Thanks for your post. Could you edit your question to provide more detail about the steps you took to install this extension?  Also could you please add your CiviCRM version and the CMS you are using (Drupal, WordPress or Joomla).  This will help people to answer your question.